# Solve : $y''+a^2y=\sin(bx) ,a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve :

$y''+a^2y=\sin(bx) ,a,b\in 
\mathbb{R}$

My solution :

Suppose the solution form is:

$$y(x)=x(A\cos(bx)+B\sin(bx))$$

$$\implies y''=-2Ab\sin(bx)+2Bb\cos(bx)+x(-Ab^2\cos(bx)-Bb^2\sin(bx))$$

Subtitue $y,\,y''$ in the original ode:
$$-2Ab\sin(bx)+2Bb\cos(bx)+x(-Ab^2\cos(bx)-Bb^2\sin(bx))+a^2(x(A\cos(bx)+B\sin(bx))=\sin(bx)$$

Then,

\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
-Ab^2+a^2A=0 \\
-Bb^2+a^2B=0 \\
\end{align}
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
-2Bb=0 \\
-2Ab=1=0 \\
\end{align}
\end{cases}

I get $A=B=0$. Where am I getting wrong? I've tried to solve it by guessing an [Ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz).

Comment: If $a= \pm b$ then multiply by $x$ for the particular solution.  But if $a \ne \pm b$ do not multiply by $x$.

Comment: I get the idea that the particular solution is $y=A\sin(bx)+B\cos(bx)$ but why is it matter if $a=b$ or $a\neq b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1:** If $a \ne b$, we have (I assume this is was the intent of the problem)

$$y_p = r \cos(bx) + s \sin(bx)$$

We get $$r = 0, s = \dfrac{1}{a^2-b^2}$$

**Case 2:** If $a = b$, we have (this is what you did)

$$y_p = x(r \cos(ax) + s \sin(ax))$$

Substituting

$$2 a s \cos(a x) - 2 a r \sin(a x) = \sin(a x)$$

This results in

$$r = -\dfrac{1}{2 a}, s = 0$$

In what you wrote, this agrees with your answer as you are solving for $A$ and $B$. From your expression, you have

$$B = 0, A = - \dfrac{1}{2 b}$$

Comment: O the second case, why I have to multiply by $x$ the particular solution when $a=b$? thanks !

Comment: Recall, we are assuming $a = b$ and have $y'' + a^2 y = \sin(ax)$. Since the homogenous solution $x_c = r \cos(a x) + s \sin(a x)$, we have the particular sharing $\sin(a x)$ with the homogenous solution, so we have to multiply by $x$. Clear?

Comment: Yes ! appreciate , thanks !